# VLC Xamarin iOS bindings. Can't play several media items with one player

Tags: ios, xamarin, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I have an app that uses VLC media player bindings in Xamarin iOS
When I play instantiate a MediaPlayer object, and play one media item as follows:

```
        var media = new Media(libVLC, new Uri(mediaItem.MediaUri));
        await media.Parse();
        Player.Play(media);
```

The player works perfectly well.
But once I want to play the next media item, that is I use the same player to play a new instance of Media,
The media player blocks my UI. It just hangs there, without any error message.

I would love to use MediaList, but as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559021/libvlcsharp-fail-to-create-medialist/56575833#56575833), the functionality is limited, and if I will like to play a specific item in my list I wouldn't be able to.

Please can someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was solved on the Discord chat.

The problematic code isn't included in the Q (please always include full repro code), but it turns out to be the LibVLC callback issue. When calling back into LibVLC from a LibVLC event, use a threadpool scheduler.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't call it in a thread safe manner. I also noticed that if I call the play in call backs and I use Xamarin's Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, it also resolves the issue.